# Search query for posts within certain period of time

Tags: mysql, wordpress

The query below is searching for posts that are followed by users (if user follows category, user or topic).

It is working if it doesn't use $time_interval.

I would like to select posts from a certain period of time (last week, last month etc.).

I hardcoded 1 month and $filter for this example. But as soon as I try to select posts from last month, the query stops working.

I tried with methods that I used in other places, but this query is much more complex and by even putting the query to work to this point was very long process of errors, so I am not sure if it is written in the best possible way.

```
  $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $term_relat_table = ;// table with term relationships
  $topic_follow_table = ;// contains which topic user follows
  $cat_follow_table = ;// contains which category user follows
  $posts_table = ;// table with posts
  $user_follow_user_table = ;// contains which users current user follows
  $votes_stats_table = ;// table with votes
  $perPage = 10; // hardcoded for this example
  $orderby = "ORDER BY vote_rating DESC, total_votes DESC"; // hardcoded for this example
  $time_interval = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 month')); // wasnt able to include in query
 //I tried placing p.post_date > $time_interval in different places in query but none seem to work.
 
$all_results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT v.topic_id AS post_id
     , v.votes_rating AS vote_rating
     , v.total_votes AS total_votes
  FROM $votes_stats_table v  
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT tf.discussion_id AS post_id 
         FROM $topic_follow_table AS tf 
        WHERE tf.current_user = %d
        UNION ALL
       SELECT p.ID AS post_id
         FROM $user_follow_user_table AS uf
         JOIN $posts_table AS p 
           ON p.post_author = uf.followed_user
        WHERE uf.current_user = %d
    -- tried placing p.post_date > %s here, and $time_interval below next to other variables

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.object_id AS post_id
      FROM $term_relat_table AS r
      JOIN $cat_follow_table AS cf 
        ON cf.cat_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
     WHERE cf.user_id = %d 
    ) AS i 
   ON i.post_id = v.topic_id   
GROUP 
   BY v.topic_id 
    $orderby 
    LIMIT %d
    OFFSET $offset", $current_user_id, $current_user_id, $current_user_id, $perPage));
```

Comment: A wonderful feature of a GROUP BY clause is that in the absence of any aggregating functions, it is never needed, and never appropriate. If you want DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT.

Comment: For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank you. Will check the link right now.